# Is it illegal to start a fake crowdfunding page in the UK?

Tags: charity

I want to donate to Greenfell Tower victims at JustGiving but some pages look dodgy and fake (hence I'm reluctant to donate).

I've read the [terms and conditions](https://www.justgiving.com/info/terms-of-service) but I'm still a bit confused. Is there a law to stop people pretending to be victims of a disaster? Will these people go to jail if I report them?

Comment: For $500, I'll take "what is fraud?" Alex!

Comment: Just because its illegal doesn't mean they wouldn't do it. Cyber fraud is rarely brought to court because the money will simply disappear

Answer (score 1):

It will be fraud under section 2 of the Fraud Act 2006.  See the CPS guidance for prosecution:

http://www.cps.gov.uk/legal/d_to_g/fraud_act/

and

http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/35/section/2

Upto 10 years in jail or an (almost) unlimited fine.  I don't know whether they would actually go to jail, but I suspect there might be an element of "make an example of them".